# Compartilhar itens com Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin

Em meu aplicativo, possuo uma funcionalidade de compartilhar nomes de uma lista criada pelo usuário.
Eu gostaria de pegar os nomes e compartilhar eles com outros apps em forma de mensagem, como WhatsApp e fins.

Tenho o seguinte código implementado:

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            type = "text/plain"
            putStringArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, arrayListOf("Daniel", "Michele"))
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Export Data")
        }
        val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartilhar lista com")
        ContextCompat.startActivity(context, chooser, null)
```

Estou passando um arrayList genérico para teste, mas da forma em que esta não funciona.
Como posso implementar isso?

Comment: talvez essa resposta aqui te ajude melhor : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952865/how-to-share-text-to-whatsapp-from-my-app ( só uma observação você vai precisar concatenar esses nomes ao invés de enviar uma lista )

Comment: Humm entendi @William. Vou verificar

Comment: Respondi minha própria solução com a respota William, depois da uma olhada

Answer (score -2):

Eu solucionei fazendo essa função

```
private fun prepareListToShare(products: List<ProductItem>) {
    val emptyList = mutableListOf<String>()
    for (product in products) {
        val append = StringBuilder().append(product.name).append(" \n")
        emptyList.add(append.toString())
    }
    val formattedNames = emptyList.joinToString("")
    state = state.copy(formattedNames = formattedNames)
}
```

Tenho uma classe de estado e quando formato a lista de nomes em uma unica string, eu passo para minha variavel de estado formattedNames, e depois pego o valor dela la na minha screen. Essa função esta em meio viewModel, pode ser que  dá para melhorar isso, mas funciona =)

Ficou assim na Screen:

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            type = "text/plain"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, **state.formattedNames**)
        }
        val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartilhar lista com")
        ContextCompat.startActivity(context, chooser, null)
```